# API cant show picture in web app instead show the url of the picture

Tags: javascript, api, express

I am working in a small web app that uses API from weather forecast to show the weather and weather conditions in current time. Every works perfect except at the moment of include a picture on my web app. Instead of that it shows the url of the picture:"src=http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/03n@2x.png>". Why this happens and how I can make it shows the picture.

My code in javascript is the next one:

```
const express=require("express");
const https=require("https");

const app=express();

app.get("/", function(req, res){

  const url="https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Taiwan&appid=16fdd9dfb819e5ad719551bc576df7f2&units=metric"

  https.get(url, function(response){
    console.log(response.statusCode);

    response.on("data", function(data){
      const weatherData=JSON.parse(data);
      const temp=weatherData.main.temp;
      const descr=weatherData.weather[0].description;
      const icon=weatherData.weather[0].icon;
      const imageURL= "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/"+ icon +"@2x.png"
      res.write("<p>The weather is curently"+descr+"</p>");
      res.write("<h1>The Temperature in Taiwan is "+temp +" degree Celsius.</h1>");
      res.write("<img> src=" +imageURL+">");
      res.send();
    })
  })
})

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Server is running on app 3000");
})
```

Comment: `res.write("<img> src=" +imageURL+">");` You're terminating your `<img>` element too early. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Images_in_HTML

Comment: Change to `res.write('<img src="' + imageURL + '">');`

Comment: You should also understand that the [`data` event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data) can emit chunked `Buffer` objects before it reaches EOF; you should be collecting the data from `data` events and only stringing it together/parsing it once the [`end` event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end) is emitted. Otherwise, you run the risk of attempting to parse an incomplete JSON document, which will cause an uncaught exception to be thrown.